# YouCompleteMe freezes when used with python-mode

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ultisnips

When I type `self.` a popup will automatically select the first one and will never change no matter what input is given. For example, *match 1 of 52* is shown.

After `<Esc>` is used to return to normal mode and enter insert mode again then YouCompleteMe works correctly again. It will show *Back at Original* and automatically updates with different input.

OS: Kubuntu 13.04

Vim version: 7.4.5

Possibly related plugin: ultisnips

Log:

```
~/vimConf  ± master ●  2014-02-12 16:37:37,251 - DEBUG - Global extra conf not loaded or no function YcmCorePreload
serving on localhost:

2014-02-12 16:37:38,931 - INFO - Received health request
2014-02-12 16:37:38,935 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:38,935 - DEBUG - Event name: BufferVisit
2014-02-12 16:37:39,012 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:39,013 - DEBUG - Event name: FileReadyToParse
2014-02-12 16:37:39,013 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /home/kamel/vimConf/my_configs.vim

2014-02-12 16:37:39,086 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:39,087 - DEBUG - Event name: BufferVisit
2014-02-12 16:37:39,147 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:39,148 - DEBUG - Event name: BufferVisit
2014-02-12 16:37:39,149 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:39,150 - DEBUG - Event name: FileReadyToParse
2014-02-12 16:37:39,150 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /home/kamel/vimConf/my_configs.vim

2014-02-12 16:37:50,482 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:50,483 - DEBUG - Event name: BufferVisit
2014-02-12 16:37:50,533 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:50,534 - DEBUG - Event name: BufferVisit
2014-02-12 16:37:50,545 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:50,545 - DEBUG - Event name: FileReadyToParse
2014-02-12 16:37:50,546 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /home/kamel/labola/src/app/mixin/alert.py

2014-02-12 16:37:50,711 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:50,712 - DEBUG - Event name: BufferVisit
2014-02-12 16:37:50,748 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:50,749 - DEBUG - Event name: BufferVisit
2014-02-12 16:37:50,750 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:37:50,752 - DEBUG - Event name: FileReadyToParse
2014-02-12 16:37:50,752 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /home/kamel/labola/src/app/mixin/alert.py

2014-02-12 16:37:57,893 - INFO - Received completion request
2014-02-12 16:37:57,894 - DEBUG - Using filetype completion: False
2014-02-12 16:37:58,055 - INFO - Received completion request
2014-02-12 16:37:58,056 - DEBUG - Using filetype completion: False
2014-02-12 16:37:58,184 - INFO - Received completion request
2014-02-12 16:37:58,184 - DEBUG - Using filetype completion: False
2014-02-12 16:37:58,297 - INFO - Received completion request
2014-02-12 16:37:58,298 - DEBUG - Using filetype completion: False
2014-02-12 16:39:37,853 - INFO - Received event notification
2014-02-12 16:39:37,853 - DEBUG - Event name: FileReadyToParse
2014-02-12 16:39:37,853 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /home/kamel/labola/src/app/mixin/alert.py
```

Screenshot:

[image]

---

Fixed:
It is due to the python-mode autocomplete. When

```
let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 0
```

is set in the `.vimrc`, it is solved!

Comment: So, if you keep typing after you press dot... what happens? YCM is supposed to make this popup appear but it should insert the first selection when you continue to type.

Comment: Do you have any plugins for python installed?

Comment: you might trying YCM without those to see if the problem persists. If it does this seems like a bug for their issue tracker on github.

Comment: Please put your answer as an answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is due to the conflict with python-mode autocomplete.

```
let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 0
```

in the `.vimrc`, it is solved!

---

As it is not recommended to use auto completion of `pymode` and `YouComplateMe` at the same time, use the following to command to cancel the `pymode` completion totally.

```
let g:pymode_rope_completion = 0
```